# How can I set pixel value on Magick++ 7?

Tags: c++, magick++

I'm able to get the values using MagickCore::Quantum, but I'm still not able to set RGB values for a pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are getting the pixels into a cache with `Magick::Image.getPixels`.

After editing the Quantum values, just call `Magick::Image.syncPixels` to copy the values back.

```c++
Magick::Image img("rose:");
// Create cache of pixel data
Magick::Quantum * pixels = img.getPixels(5, 5, 1, 1);
// Set values
Magick::Color green("GREEN");
pixels[0] = green.quantumRed();
pixels[1] = green.quantumGreen();
pixels[2] = green.quantumBlue();
// Copy cache back.
img.syncPixels();
img.write("output.png");
```

Comment: Thanks, @emcconville!